# Testing React Component with Jest/Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to use Enzyme's shallow wrapper to get the instance of my component and calling my class function over it. It shows me this error: 
***TypeError: tree.instance(...).onCampaignSelected is not a function***

```
class ToolbarPage extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.onCampaignSelected = this.onCampaignSelected.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      item: null
    }
  }

  onCampaignSelected (item) {
     this.setState({item})
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <MyComponent onItemSelected={this.onCampaignSelected} />
    )
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state){
  buttons: state.toolbar.buttons
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ToolbarPage);
```

My test case looks like this

```
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import ToolbarPage from './ToolbarPage';
import configureStore from 'configureStore';

const store = configureStore();

const props = {
 store,
 isLoggedIn: false,
 messageCounter: 0
}

describe('<ToolbarPage />', () => {
  it('allows to select campaign', () => {
    const tree = shallow(<ToolbarPage {...props}/>);
    tree.instance().onCampaignSelected();
  })
})
```

I also figured out that it is a wrapped component, so I won't get this function on the wrapped component. How do I access this function?

Comment: The code seems to be ok. What does `tree.debug()` return?. Also, don't you get error that `props` are `undefined`? Didn't you miss something in the provided code sample?

Answer (score 0):

[shallow](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md) does not render the full set of components with all of their properties & methods. It is intended for basic "did this thing render what I expected?" testing.

[mount](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/mount.md) will give you *everything* and should allow you to test whatever you need. It is very useful for testing event handling & manipulating the state of components to test the interactions between components.

Comment: It should let you call instance methods though.